# how to calculate non zero values without gap

Tags: excel

Please note the following values in column A & B.

```
1    2280  
2    0  
3    1250  
4    0  
5    1245  
6    0  
7    0  
8    0  
9    1258  
10   0
```

i need following by formula in column C & D. please help

```
1    2280  
3    1250  
5    1245  
9    1258
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C1 use:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$1:$B$10)-ROW($B$1)+1)/($B$1:$B$10<>0),ROWS($A$1:$A1)),"")
```

It returns the list of row numbers where there is no zero in B for the designated range.  Copy it down.  It will display "" when it runs out of number to display.

In D2 use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,C1),"")
```

It will display the corresponding value in B to the row number listed in C. Copy the formula down. Like the first formula the IFERROR will make it display "" when it runs out of number to look up.

Comment: Its really comforting to see this solution. Thanks in deep. Further in C1 formula, can i replace G$9:G9 at end with A$9:A9???

Comment: yes, actually you should change it to $A$1:A1, I will edit my answer to reflect this.  that particular chunk of the formula is essentially a counter that increases by one each row its copied down.

Answer (score 0):

Formula in C:

```
=IF($B1>0;A1;"")
```

Formula in D:

```
=IF($B1>0;B1;"")
```

VBA solution:

```
Sub values()

  linea = 1

  For Each cell In Range("b1:b10")

  If cell > 0 Then
    Cells(linea, 3) = cell
    Cells(linea, 4) = Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column - 1)
    linea = linea + 1
  End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Your formula method display blanks or "" rows when the value is zero.  It does nothing to compress the list as per the desired output example.